# Swift function from external library not importing

Tags: swift, xcode, import, libraries, swift-package-manager

I am trying to create an external swift library full of functions I can call in other projects. I followed the basic steps to creating a library in Swift

I ran

`swift package init`

my package.swift looks like

```swift
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "TestProject",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries produced by a package, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "TestProject",
            targets: ["TestProject"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "TestProject",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "TestProject",
            dependencies: ["TestProject"]),
    ]
)
```

and ran `swift package generate-xcodeproj` to make the project.

then uploaded the project to Github and loaded it into a different project using Swift Package Manager. It loaded in just fine.

I created a simple SwiftUI project for testing my library. in the library, I have added the function

```swift
func test() -> String{
    return("This was good!")
}
```

and then in the project, in my ContentView.swift file I added `import TestProject` in the import statements (which did build correctly) and attempted to call `test()` in the file by setting the value of the default `Text("Hello World")` to `Text(test())` to see if it would work.

I was prompted with an error stating that `test()` was not a defined

> Use of unresolved identifier 'test'

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong as far as importing my library and I've found surprisingly little while trying to look into this.

my TestProject.swift file located in `/Sources/TestProject/' as generated by swift on the init

```swift
struct SwiftSciduct {
    var text = "Hello, World!"
}

func test() -> String{
    return("This was good!")
}
```

my contentView.swift file

```swift
import SwiftUI
import TestProject

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text(test())
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Kind of at a loss of why this function isn't useable in the main project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access `test()` because it has defaulted to the `internal` access level. You need to mark it as `public` or `open` in order for other modules to see it.

Comment: I knew it had to be something so incredibly simple.